# Is MacOS Catalina stripping executable file permissions in zip files?

Tags: java, zip, executable, macos-catalina, apache-commons-codec

I have created a zip file using OpenJDK 11 and Apache Commons Compress 1.20 which is returned by an API using a Netty server. This zip file contains a gradle wrapper that has executable file permissions (755).

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  mygroup  5766 Aug 24 16:03 gradlew
```

I zip it with Commons Compress, return it in the API response, and the browser saves the zip to disk.

If I extract the zip file in *MacOS Mojave* the gradle wrapper file looks like this (with extended file attributes listing):

```
ls -al@ gradlew
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 myuser  mygroup    5766 Nov 30  1979 gradlew
    com.apple.quarantine        56
```

Ok, it's quarantined, but still executable. It works fine to execute it.

If I extract the zip file in *MacOS Catalina* the gradle wrapper file looks like this (with extended file attributes listing):

```
ls -al@ gradlew
-rw-rw-r--@  1 myuser  mygroup    5766 Nov 30  1979 gradlew
    com.apple.quarantine        57
```

The executable file permissions have been removed by Catalina. Is there some way to circumvent this, except by adding the executable file permissions after unzipping?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across similar issue recently and found the solution at [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io) [source code](https://github.com/spring-io/initializr/blob/10d7e857c79e2d3e9bc436b1e5ab189a363c6e90/initializr-web/src/main/java/io/spring/initializr/web/controller/ProjectGenerationController.java#L165)

In short, the solution is to modify permissions of gradlew archive entry to make it executable after unarchiving.

Here is an example of code I used, it is on Kotlin but can be easily converted into Java if required.

```
val entry = ZipArchiveEntry(file, name)

entry.unixMode = if (Files.isDirectory(path)) {
     UnixStat.DIR_FLAG or UnixStat.DEFAULT_DIR_PERM
} else {
    UnixStat.FILE_FLAG or if (entryName == "gradlew") UnixStat.DEFAULT_DIR_PERM else UnixStat.DEFAULT_FILE_PERM
}
```